# Database Architecture & Design

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I am building a web application for project management which will be hosted on my servers. My application design is like this

> 1 - user register
>
> 2 - domain name will be created i.e abc.domain-name.com

I am planning to have one different  database for each user with their username as prefix of the tables .
i.e

> DB name :  abc_db\
>
> ```
>       Tables   - abc_projects
>                -  abc_users
>                - etc....
> ```

So is this a scalable and reliable solution for high  traffic site..?

Comment: Do you want to have a database, for each user?

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli yes.. i m thinking so... can u suggest me any other reliable fast solution ?

Comment: You are talking about Multi-Tenant implementations. Noel Herrick http://www.noelherrick.com/blog/designing-multi-tenanted-databases starts a series on multi-tenant design.  Microsoft gives an overview of multi-tenant designs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: Any real life example ? How to implement this ?